# How to change Kubernetes configuration key file from controller-manager and apiserver to point to the same x509 RSA key?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kops

I am having tiller panic crash as detailed in helm FAQ (https://docs.helm.sh/using_helm/) under the question
**Q: Tiller crashes with a panic:**
`panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation...`

The FAQ answer suggests

> To fix this, you will need to change your Kubernetes configuration.
>   Make sure that --service-account-private-key-file from
>   controller-manager and --service-account-key-file from apiserver point
>   to the same x509 RSA key.

I've tried to search online and read the docs at (https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/service-accounts-admin/) which states

> You must pass a service account private key file to the token
>   controller in the controller-manager by using the
>   --service-account-private-key-file option. The private key will be used to sign generated service account tokens. Similarly, you must
>   pass the corresponding public key to the kube-apiserver using the
>   --service-account-key-file option. The public key will be used to verify the tokens during authentication.

and the docs at https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/
The docs explain concepts well, but no specifics on actually changing the config.

How do I change my Kubernetes configuration as the FAQ answer suggests?

> Make sure that --service-account-private-key-file from
>   controller-manager and --service-account-key-file from apiserver point
>   to the same x509 RSA key.

Details:
using kops and gossip based k8s cluster

Answer (score 0):

I have found through trial and error that `helm ls` seems to have a bug for my setup, or maybe `helm ls` is expected to show the error if there are no releases to be shown.

Right after `helm init`, `helm ls` would show the error `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation...`,
but if you just went ahead and used helm,
e.g. `helm install stable/<package>`, the chart is deployed successfully.

And after the charts are deployed, calling `helm ls` no longer returns the error, and correctly shows the deployed charts (releases).
I have confirmed it using `kubectl get pods`, `kubectl get services` and `kubectl get deployments`, the released objects are all running.